# Creating dynamic time series plots on web pages

Tags: web-services, web-applications, web, graph, time-series

I have the following requirement:

1) A user browser fetches data points (essentially time series) from the server and plots on the web page.

2) User should be able to alter(also view) the data points using the mouse and doing this should alter the plot dynamically. In this way, user can alter all the data points until he is satisfied.

3) Finally, user needs to send his "version of data points" back to the server.

I am new to web development and would like to know if there anything out there already that I can refer to or any set of standard tools that I can use?

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at the [`googleVis` package](http://cran.r-project.org/package=googleVis) of the R software. The package provides and interface between R and the [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/). This can be a convenient way to generate the html displaying a graphic of the data.

In [this document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis.pdf) the authors of the package explain how to use `googleVis` along with the packages `Rook` and `shiny`. These packages allow the user to upload a data file and update the graphic. The user would have to edit the file outside the browser but you could add a form in order to edit the file through the browser and update the graphic when the data are submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will take a look at these tool.